# Django API on Wordpress website

Tags: django, wordpress

I have a wordpress website, and a plugin I am building for it. This plugin needs to use an API written in Django (Python), to show some data. I have the source code of the API, but it's not integrate it yet. I have to integrate it on the same sever/WP install. Is it possible to make this work? If yes, how?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just create a Django view to handle the API requests, and return data in a format that will be easy for your PHP code to read, like JSON. It sounds like you've already gotten about that far, so where are you having problems?

Comment: My problem is that I never did this before, and I have no idea how to do it. I usually don't work with neither wordpress nor django/python, let alone those two togheter.

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure would look like this:

**On the Python/Django Side**

Make a Django view that takes a few arguments. For example, if I had a database hooked up to a Django project that had a bunch of data about store sales (including the day and time they occurred), I could let my Wordpress site retrieve all sales in a given month with something like `http://www.mydjangoproject.com/api/<month>/<year>/`. My request would be routed to my Django API view, the view would take the month and year and then query the DB for all sales in that month. It would then [encode that information as JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), and render it.

**On the PHP/Wordpress Side**

Now, on my Wordpress site, I can load the transactions from a given month like this:

```
# get the transactions for December 2013
$month = 12
$year = 2013
$JSON = file_get_contents(http://www.mydjangoproject.com/api/$month/$year/);

# associative array of transactions
$transactions = json_decode($JSON);
```

Then, you can use the `$transactions` array to do whatever you need with it.